# Android - Editor.Blink() is called in background state every 500ms

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to find out what's running while my application is in the background state (the CPU usage is not zero).
And I saw this `Editor.Blink()` was called so frequently.
It looks like there is a Timer which is trying to blink the cursor.
But it makes no sense to blink it in the background.
Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Here's the trace log.
[image]

I'm using API 25 with support library 25.3.1.

Comment: Is the editor focused?  Have you tried remove its focus?

Comment: The application is in the background state. It can't be focused. And the `EditText` is not displaying on the screen. It's in another fragment of the `ViewPager` which is not visible when I hit the home button.

Comment: But it could have been focused when last onscreen. See if making sure it gets unfocused when you go onscreen fixes things

Comment: You're right, I call `EditText.clearFocus()` in `setUserVisibleHint` and `onPause` then it's gone. I thought that the Android SDK itself should handle this well.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but I'm not entirely surprised.  There was a report a week or two ago about Visual Studio using around 20% CPU for the same bug (cursor refresh at 60fps).  Its surprisingly common.